# Surjective homomorphisms out of $D_{2n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have this theorem in my notes:

> There is a homormophism $f:D_{2n} \rightarrow G$ with $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$ if and only if
>
> 1. $x^2=e$
> 2. $y^n=e$
> 3. $x^{-1}yx=y^{-1}$

Now this is what I want to prove:

If $|x|=2$, $|y|=n$, then $f$ is one-to-one provided $n>2$.

Proof:

If $|y|=n$ and $n=2$, then $x$ might be equal to $y$... so $f(a)=f(b)$ but $a \not= b$

Do you think my proof is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, G can be any group. So this theorem tells us whether or not there is a homomorphism from $D_{2n}$ to G.

Comment: Isn't there an assumption saying that $G=\langle x,y\rangle$ in your problem while proving $f$ is an injective?

Comment: If $f$ is a homomorphism, why does it have to be injective?

Comment: @Ludolila I just want to prove that if n>2, then the homomorphism needs to be injective

Comment: @Babak S. I'm not sure. It doesn't say that in my notes.

Comment: @Artus: Don't you think if $|x|=2$ and $f$ is a injective and for example $|G|$ of odd order we will face to a contradiction? I mean we should know more about $G$.

Comment: You do not seem to have even attempted to prove it! You have just remarked that if $n=2$ then it is possible that $f$ is not injective, which is true but irrelevant. You need to prove that if $n>2$ then $f$ is injective - which is also true - there is no need to assume that $G = \langle x,y \rangle$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. Is it ok if you give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: When $n > 2$, $xy \ne yx$, so we cannot have $x \in \langle y \rangle$, and hence $|\langle x,y \rangle| \ge 2n$. So $|{\rm Im}(f)| \ge |G|$ and $f$ must be injective.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, you said $xy \not= yx$ because y is not equal to its own inverse, right? But then we have $y\not=xyx$. If we raise both sides of the equation to the power n, then we get $y^n = e \not= xy^nx = x^2$. But how is that true, because the order of x is 2...

Comment: So you must have made a mistake in what you wrote! See if you can find it.

Comment: @Artus I encourage you to answer your own question once you figure it out.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Ok I'll try to think about it more, but I don't know if I can...